# MBP Late 2011 15" Windows 10 Installation Problems

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, partition

Just two days ago, the machine had a Windows 8 partition on it, but it was full of malware slowing it down and hurting it. I backed up all important files and formatted the drive, so to install Windows 10 from a WININSTALL USB drive, I created on a different computer. I've tried as many things as I could think of, or find online, even going as far as to do a full wipe of the entire Hard Drive.

Boot Camp Assistant, when functional, give me the error that "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk has a mbr partition table, On EFI system window can only be installed to GPT disks."

Installing on a partition of pure Free Space returns the error "Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration. Installation cannot proceed."

I've done some reading, and it seems this older model isn't EFI compatible. If this is true, what alternatives do I have? If not, what can I do to move things forward. Thank you!

-Dan

Answer (score 1):

This is for that person looking at this thread some months or years from now, knowing what I did. Just go out to your local Target, WalMart, Best Buy, what have you, and buy some DVD-Rs. A ten pack cost me $7.00. I then burned the Windows 10 ISO to one of them and installed from there. Worked like a charm. Only problem was I had trouble booting into Mac OSX after the installation, but I'm sure I'll figure that out, too. I will update this (hopefully) when all is 100% up to snuff.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have a single drive or are you using a 2nd hard drive?

If you have a 2nd drive, I would try wiping the hard drive again, so it has neither MBR nor GPT partitioning data anywhere, and then try Boot Camp Assistant on the completely blank hard drive.

Comment: Do you mean I should try to install Windows on an external drive? I would be worried about it disconnecting while running, but I do have a 1TB USB drive. The main hard drive right now is sitting at approximately 745GB free, after the wipe. When I attempted to use Boot Camp Assistant, it didn't allow me to install Windows from an EFI drive.

Answer (score 0):

when booting your mac with option key, you have the choice to select either BIOS-emulated/Legacy WININSTALL or UEFI-WININSTALL. It seems you only tried the 2nd way. the first way let you install windows on MBR schema.

I did both ways with my mid 2011 MBA and for Windows 10 the MBA hardware behaves differently and I had problems with the internal intel 3000 HD graphics.
With BIOS/Legacy install all is fine.